# a4988 Pololu and Unipolar Stepper Motor

Tags: arduino, stepper-motor

I currently have an Unipolar Stepper Motor with 6 wire and a A4988 Pololu Stepper Driver also Arduino Board, but there are not any guide to connect Unipolar Motor with Driver, Only Bipolar. 
  Someone help me solve this problem, does this driver support Unipolar ? and How?

Many thanks!

Comment: Yout motor is like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vUZYF.gif), to use as a bipolar motor just disregard the middle tap wire (2) and use the end points (1 and 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bipolar driver will drive both uni and bi polar stepper motors. Just wire as bipolar, and leave the center tapped coils disconnected.

Comment: Not all unipolar have six wires, there are also five wire motors with the tap of both coils joined which can't be used the way you describe. Fortunately the OP has a six wire motor.

Comment: @Tut My comment referred to using the motor as is, dismantling the motor is a totally different ballgame.

Comment: @Tut Oh.. I just took a look at the the link and when I saw the photo I thought it was about internal modification, my bad. It's the first time I see this idea about the common tap and its effect, I have no idea if it works or not so I can't comment on that.

Comment: @alexan_e I have deleted my previous comments about connecting a 5-wire motor to a bipolar drive. I am having serious reservations about doing that.